# Find the poles of $f(z)=\frac 1{1+z^w}$ for $w \gt 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

I am trying to use contour integration on the following integrand between $0$ and $\infty$, however I am not sure how to go about finding the poles for it:

$$f(z)=\frac 1{1+z^w},w \in \mathbb Z:w \gt 1$$

Consider the denominator equal to zero:

$$1+z^w=0$$

$$\Rightarrow z^w=-1$$

$$\Rightarrow z=-1^{\frac 1w} \equiv \sqrt[w] z $$

How would I go about determining the types of poles we would have for $f(z)$ given the many different forms it could take dependent on $w$?

Comment: What is $w$? An integer? Rational? Real?

Comment: it mainly depends if $w$ is integer or not...

Comment: I know, forgive me, but the question sheet I have just states $w \gt 1$. Let us suppose then that $w$ is an integer.

Comment: If $w$ is an integer, then $f$ will have poles.  Else, if $w$ is real-valued, then $f$ will have a branch point singularity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so $w$ is a natural number greater than $1$. So all you need is to solve $z^w = -1$, that is to say, all the $w$-roots of $-1$.

These are unique and there are exactly $w$ of them, so your function will have poles of order $1$ at the $w$ roots of $-1$. They all lie on the unit circle.

Comment: I see! It's a lot more clearer now, thanks!

Comment: I understand how there will be $w$ distinct poles, and that they will each have order one, but how would I move to calculate the residues of them to the end of evaluating the half contour of the integrand? Given that part of the evaluation involves taking the sum of the residues? I know how to find the residue of a pole of order one, but how would I go about writing this down when there are $w$ of them?

Comment: @JeremyJeffreyJames As you usually would! Determine which (and how many) roots are inside your contour, then sum all of them. Specifially, the residue in $z_0$ is $$\frac 1{wz_0^{w-1}} = \frac{-z_0}{w}$$

Answer (score 2):

If $w$ is an integer with $w \ge 1$ then $f=\frac{1}{1+z^w}$ will have singularities given by

$$1+z^w=0\implies z^w=-1 \implies z^w=e^{i\pi (2n-1)} \implies z=e^{i(2n-1)\pi/w}$$

for $n=1, 2, \cdots ,w$.

---

NOTE:

It is interesting to remark that if $w\le 1$, then we see that $f$ has the same poles as the case with $|w|$.  To see this, write for $w<0$

$$f=\frac{1}{1+z^w}=\frac{1}{1+z^{-|w|}}=\frac{z^{|w|}}{1+z^{|w|}}$$

Comment: Could you explain for me please how it is that n can take a value from $1$ to $w$. I understand that it will take integer values, but why until $w$?

Comment: @JeremyJeffreyJames  Sure. After $w$, the terms repeat due to periodicity of the complex exponential.  Let's try $w=3$.  Then, we have $z_1 = e^{i\pi/3}$, $z_2 = e^{i3\pi/3}=e^{i\pi}=-1$, and $z_3 = e^{i5\pi/3}=e^{-i\pi/3}$.  If we take $n=4$, then $e^{i7\pi/3}=e^{i\pi/3}=z_1$, which is not a new pole/root.

Comment: Yes of course! Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @JeremyJeffreyJames You're welcome!  It was my pleasure.